# Visual studio 2015 openmp support

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, openmp

I'm having trouble getting OpenMP support in Visual Studio 2015.

I've configured the project options to use /openmp (project->properties->C/C++->language->OpenMP support:yes), the code is as follows (very simple code, to test OpenMP):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int n = 0;

#pragma omp parallel
    {
        std::cout << std::endl << "Hello World!";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Only one thread runs and "Hello World!" is printed only once.

Comment: You should check available number of threads with [`omp_get_num_threads`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdeb73hc.aspx) function, and if the result would be 1 set the number of threads you want with [`omp_set_num_threads`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e16bady3.aspx). There are also other approaches to set the number of threads for OpenMP.

Comment: Yes, I tried that earlier, still only one thread.
Same results by setting adding num_threads(4) to the #pragma omp parallel directive: single thread, single print.
I've come across some info online that not all versions of VS support OpenMP, so I suppose it's because I'm using VS2015 Community.

Answer (score 7):

I was able to compile the program with `VS2015 Community Version 14.0 Update 1` on `Windows 8.1 64bit` with OpenMP support.

Below, follow a list of steps that may help:

- After create a new project and paste the source code, go to

`Project-> Properties -> C/C++ -> Language`

Change `Open MP Support` to `Yes(/openmp)`

Click `Apply`

- On the left menu, go to `Command Line` and confirm that `/openmp`
  appears somewhere at the compiler's options.

If it appears, click `Ok` and build the project.

---

Before run the program, put a breakpoint at the line:

`int n = 0;`

Run the the program by clicking on `Local Windows Debugger`

When the program stops at the breakpoint, go to `Debug -> Windows -> Disassembly`

Somewhere, near the breakpoint, look for an assembly line like:

`call   __vcomp_fork (?????????h)`

If you find this line, chances are that openmp is ok and running.

---

Some other checks that can help:

Get a tool from Windows Sysinternals like [Process Explorer (GUI)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer) or [ListDLLs (command line)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896656).

**ListDLLs:**

With the program stopped at the breakpoint, open task manager and look for the `PID` of the process.

Open a command prompt and run the command:

`listdlls [PID] | findstr -i vcomp`

Should appear something like `VCOMP140D.DLL` or `VCOMP140.DLL` or `VCOMP????.DLL`.

If it not appears, probably the compiler couldn't find the openmp dll so you'll have to see if this  library is available at some point on your system.

---

Two last tips that may save your time:

If you change any configuration (e.g. `Debug -> Release` or `x86 -> x64`),
check again if `Command Line` has the `/openmp` option set ok.

If you try to force the compiler to C language (instead of C++), maybe the pragma:

`#pragma omp parallel for`

will not work (*Update: Apparently this problem does not happen anymore on VS2017*).

It shows me the message:

`INTERNAL COMPILER ERROR in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\CL.exe'`

Come back the compiler to C++ language and the `parallel for` will works ok.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer: I was not able to get the compiler to accept /openmp through the config/GUI, but compiling in console with cl.exe /openmp works.