# Qt with Openmp is not giving any speedup in Windows, i am using Visual Studio 2013 and Qt 5.5

Tags: c++, qt, openmp

[In VS 2013](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cmlmo.png)Here is the code, its not giving speed improvement when Openmp is used for bringing parallelism in for loop. I want to bring down the time taken to 20ms. Is it possible?

Current execution time is around 150ms with or without Openmp.

```
speedtest.pro

TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++11
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt
SOURCES += main.cpp
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -openmp
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <omp.h>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

void fun(bool *c, int *a, int aSize, int *b, int bSize)
{
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i<aSize; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j<bSize; j++)
            if ((a[i*3] - b[j*3])*(a[i*3] - b[j*3]) + 
                (a[i*3 + 1] - b[j*3 + 1])*(a[i*3 + 1] - b[j*3 + 1]) 
              + (a[i*3 + 2] - b[j*3 + 2])*(a[i*3 + 2] - b[j*3 + 2])<30)
                c[i*bSize + j] = 1;
    }
}


int main()
{

    const int aSize = 16000;
    const int bSize = 6000;

    int *a = new int[aSize*3];
    int *b = new int[bSize*3];
    bool *c = new bool[aSize*bSize];

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < aSize; i++){
        a[i*3] = (int)i;
        a[i*3 + 1] = (int)i;
        a[i*3 + 2] = (int)i;
    }
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < bSize; i++){
        b[i*3] = (int)i;
        b[i*3 + 1] = (int)i;
        b[i*3 + 2] = (int)i;
    }

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < aSize*bSize; i++){
        c[i] = 0;
    }

    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> start, end;
    start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();



    fun(c, a, aSize, b, bSize);


    end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();


    int c1 = 0;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < aSize*bSize; i++){
        if (c[i] == 0){
            c1 = 1; break;
        }
    }

    if (c1 == 1)
        cout << "Collision" << endl;
    else
        cout << "No collision" << endl;

    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds = end - start;
    std::time_t end_time = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(end);

    std::cout << "finished computation at " << std::ctime(&end_time)
        << "elapsed time: " << 1000 * elapsed_seconds.count() << "ms\n";
    getch();
        delete [] a;
        delete [] b;
        delete [] c;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does it give you speedup on other platforms?

Comment: Let me try same in Visual Studio then, but I need it to happen in Qt as my application is in Qt.

Comment: Making loops like that parallel will probably cause L1, L2 & L3 cache thrashing.  Would suggest you get a tool to check cache performance.

Comment: Use `QElapsedTimer` for measuring.

Comment: I compiled it with gcc on Linux. Firstly, times were the same cause I compiled it wrong. Even though I added correct headers and gomp, I had to add -fopenmp to gcc. I know that you are using different compiler, but double check your compilation. After correct compilation, I get around 3x speed-up.

Comment: One more thing, shouldn't be QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += fopenmp instead of openmp?

Comment: Your application is not "in" Qt. There's no such thing. It is a C++ WINAPI application that happens to use Qt framework. It has nothing to do with whether the compiler will generate parallelized code, other than Qt's build system providing compile flags that you might need to override.

Comment: @foxfireee - so you won't be getting down to 20 msec on anything below 8-10 core CPU

Comment: @ddriver That's right, but I have only 4 cores on that particular PC. PCs with 12 cores exist. I would say 20ms is possible.

Comment: It may not be weird, but actually anything above 4 cores is pretty rare still. Even high end i7 is still stuck at 4 cores, for 6-10 cores you have to go for E edition CPU, for anything above that - xeon. 150 ms itself is not all that bad, unless you do thousands of those in a row, I'd say it doesn't really merit MP, it can be an async operation just so that it doesn't block the main thread.

Comment: I tried running same code in Visual Studio 2013, my PC is xenon  having 8cores, and yes its still showing 150ms. I agree, i cannot achieve 20ms with 8cores, but atleast a 50ms should be possible no?

Comment: @foxfiree, there was a memory allocation error in code, can you try the current code that is edited. Why Openmp is not showing any effect in Windows? Thanks for giving hope that it ran faster in Linux.

Comment: @Jerin I think your problem is compilation. Have you checked if openmp flag is correct? Which compiler you use? GCC accepts fopenmp flag, not openmp

Comment: @Jerin new code - 3.48x speedup with openmp. My guess is compilation issues. If you have gcc, try compilation from command line: g++ code.cpp -std=c++11 -fopenmp (eventually pass also gomp library and headers location)

Comment: @foxfire, Oh that's good news! Well now I am trying in Windows,Visual Studio 2013, 64 bit, 8cores, Openmp enabled, still 150ms it is. What can I do to compile it properly in VS?

Comment: @Jerin In options of the project you have C++->language->openMP support, set it to yes - it adds `/openmp` flag for _**cl**_ compiler. Make sure you are compiling x64 application in _**release**_ mode.

Comment: @foxfire, I have done what you said. X64, rlease, use Openmp option ticked (yes), but no improvement in speed. Please click on 'In VS 2013' part of my post (on top, at start), screenshot of my Visual Studio project.

Comment: @Jerin I'm out of ideas, maybe look closely at this question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35578916/visual-studio-2015-openmp-support]. ExNihiloAdNihile compiled succesfully using console and **cl** (Visual Studio compiler). Try that also. Check resulting command line in options of the project, copy it to your console and see if you have some improvement.

Comment: I think overhead of thread calls is compromising the speed improvement due to parallelism(in Windows).. (some how its not happening in Linux)

Comment: @Jerin Something is wrong, for sure. I am able to manipulate OMP_THREAD_LIMIT and get different results for 1, 2, 3 and 4 threads. Last thing, print `omp_get_thread_limit()`  result in the code and check if it is set up to 1 - it would be the answer why you are getting the same results.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add before the for   `#pragma omp parallel for`

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i=0;i<N;++i)
{
   //....
}
```

With Qt you need to add, in your .pro file:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -fopenmp
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -fopenmp
```

Comment: #pragma omp parallel for
  for(int i=0;i<aSize;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<bSize;j++)

Comment: You don't need to know how to "write" code: Just write it as you normally would, then select it, and click the `{}` button. That's all!

Comment: Please check the code i have posted, pragma is already there. But i am not getting any speed improvement in Windows platform (VS 2013)

Answer (score 0):

Do not measure time with clock! It measures clock ticks. If you are using many cores of the CPU, results can be wrong.

Use for example [std::chrono](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono)

Comment: That should be a comment.

Comment: @ddriver Why? This can be an answer why measured times are the same. Won't check that because I do not have VS, but this is my guess.

Comment: clock() is not very accurate, but it is not **that much** inaccurate

Comment: I did the same mistake when I was measuring a loop parallelized with parallel extensions from standard library. Time was multiplied by the number of cores, it's not about precision. Clock in linux measured ticks and gathered results from all cores.

Comment: Thanks, I edited code, but its giving same time (around 150ms) 

            std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> start, end;
            start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        
            fun(c,a,aSize,b,bSize);

            end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

Comment: `clock()` will work with the MSVC C run-time libraries but not with unix (Linux, BSD, macOS,...) C run-time libraries. In general it's best to use `omp_get_wtime()` to avoid this issue.