# OpenMP won't run more than one thread

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, openmp

The following code won't run more than one thread. I tried the following with no success (Visual Studio 2015 Update 3):

- enabled support for OpenMP (**Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Language -> Open MP Support -> Yes (/openmp)**)
- defined the OMP_NUM_THREADS environment variable in Visual Studio (**Configuration Properties -> Debugging -> Environment -> OMP_NUM_THREADS=4**)
- defined the OMP_NUM_THREADS environment variable in Windows
- called omp_set_num_threads(4) within the code
- tried using #pragma omp parallel num_threads(4)

I haven't been able to get more than one thread.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    int nb_threads = omp_get_max_threads();
    printf(">> omp_get_max_thread()\n>> %i\n", nb_threads);

    omp_set_num_threads(4);
    printf(">> omp_set_num_threads(4)\n");

    nb_threads = omp_get_num_threads();
    printf(">> omp_get_num_threads()\n>> %i\n", nb_threads);

    int id;
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        id = omp_get_thread_num();
        printf(">> omp_get_thread_num()\n>> %i\n", id);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
>> omp_get_max_thread()
>> 8
>> omp_set_num_threads(4)
>> omp_get_num_threads()
>> 1
>> omp_get_thread_num()
>> 0
```

Comment: I don't see you doing any operations that would actually benefit from (or could) run on multiple threads, so what do you actually expect? A call to `printf` is not parellalizable.. Openmp is not *magic* that will automatically make your code faster (nor will using multiple threads) - there has to be some parallelism to exploit (and the overhead of creating threads has to be worth it compared to single thread execution)

Comment: @JesperJuhl, I am already aware that this code doesn't benefit from multi-threading. This exercise is for the sake of the demonstration which I found in many OpenMP tutorial such as this one (https://youtu.be/FQ1k_YpyG_A?t=3m30s). I expected, by explicitly asking for 4 threads with the call to "omp_set_num_threads(4)", to output four times the printf statement with the corresponding ID of the thread. I also tried with "#pragma omp parallel for" with a parallelizable for loop with no success before posting.

Comment: Your code works fine http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d84a2566db2aad4f

Comment: Note that I would use #pragma omp parallel private(id) and do printf in a critical region.

Comment: Note that calling `omp_get_num_threads()` outside of a parallel region I think is pointless. Do this call inside a parallel region.

Comment: Yep, I just looked it up in the standard. `omp_get_num_threads()` returns 1 in the sequential region of code just like you observe. The only thing surprising is that in a parallel region you only see one thread.

Comment: Do you compile in release mode or debug mode?

Comment: I think MSVC allows you to link the OpenMP runtime libraries even if you don't enable OpenMP (this is not possible in GCC) so the fact that you can call the runtime libraries is not proof that OpenMP is enabled.

Comment: I found an online MSVC compiler. Your code works with /openmp http://rextester.com/KEEO29929. So you have not managed to enable OpenMP.

Comment: try compiling your code from the command line. I have not done this with Windows in a while but it goes something like `cl.exe foo.cpp /openmp`.

Comment: @Z boson, I tried compiling using both debug and release mode with the same result.

Comment: @Z boson, I followed this walkthrough from MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms235639.aspx) to compile my code from command line with the /openmp option. This worked. In short, I opened the "Developper Command Prompt for VS2015" and typed "cl <path-to-my-file.cpp> /openmp". In my case, I needed to run as administrator in order to use the "Developper Command Prompt for VS2015" (I am on a corporate PC). So I decided to try running Visual Studio as administrator and this worked! My question now becomes: why is this not working if not running as administrator?

Comment: Ok, for some reason, after enabling OpenMP in Visual Studio as administrator, it is now working also when launching Visual Studio as regular user.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you only have a single `id`, and access to it is serialized. By giving each thread access to its own `id`, they can execute in parallel, so we want to change the pragma to:

```
#pragma omp parallel private(id)
```

This way, access to `id` isn't serialized, and each thread can execute on its own, so we get output like this:

```
>> omp_get_max_thread()
>> 4
>> omp_set_num_threads(4)
>> omp_get_num_threads()
>> 1
>> omp_get_thread_num()
>> 0
>> omp_get_thread_num()
>> 3
>> omp_get_thread_num()
>> 2
>> omp_get_thread_num()
>> 1
```

Comment: I also tried with "#pragma omp parallel for" with a parallelizable for loop with no success before posting.

Comment: if you want work sharing, you must use `omp parallel for`,  not just `omp parallel `

Comment: Your answer does not answer the OP's question.

Comment: @Zboson: I don't see where the OP actually asked a question, so I had to guess what he really intended to ask (and apparently you did also--and guessed differently than I did).

Answer (score 0):

You should use the compiler option `/openmp` to  enable `#pragma omp` in source code.

> If `/openmp` is not specified in a compilation, the compiler ignores OpenMP clauses and directives.

Comment: As mentioned in my initial post, I enabled OpenMP within Visual Studio by going to Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Language -> Open MP Support -> Yes (/openmp). I double checked by making sure the /openmp flag was present in "Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Command Line -> All Options" of the project properties.

Comment: @SBD Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35701375/6579744) that explained how to configure VC++ for  OpenMP.

Comment: I already did read this thread before posting. Actually, when looking at the assembly code (Debug -> Windows -> Disassembly), I can't find the line "call   __vcomp_fork (?????????h)", which is an indication that there is something wrong. The post does not develop on what to do in that case...

Comment: The interesting thing with MSVC is that even without `/openmp` it still allows the OpenMP runtime libraries.

Comment: @Zboson Ok, but /openmp is required only for enabling omp directives.

Comment: @SBD Try setting compiler options as [environment variable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kezkeayy.aspx) and set `/openmp` as the first option.